# How to setup Reportviewer 12 in a web form

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, webforms

I get error JavaScript runtime error: 'Microsoft' is undefined
when executing $create(Microsoft.Reporting.WebFormsClient.ReportViewer,
I us Visual Studio 2015 and .net 4.6.2

Answer (score 0):

1. Set reportViewer.Visible = false
2. Collect input selection
3. Set various reportViewer properties

Now I get error messages that make sense, that I can fix.